# Generating PDF in Bangla Language with reportlab python library

Tags: python, pdf-generation, reportlab

I have try to generate PDF in BANGALA labguage. Here I added Bangla Uni-Code font. But My PDF is not genated  correclty. here I add Code Snippet and output of Imag. Why Font is not working properly or PDF is not generated properly in Bangla?

Here is my code

```
import os
from io import BytesIO
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4, inch, landscape
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Table, TableStyle, Paragraph, Frame
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet, ParagraphStyle
from reportlab.lib.enums import TA_LEFT, TA_CENTER, TA_RIGHT, TA_JUSTIFY
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics
from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont
from django.http import HttpResponse


def download_pdf_file(request):

    # Create the HttpResponse object with the appropriate PDF headers.
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="somefilename.pdf"'
    buffer = BytesIO()


    doc = SimpleDocTemplate(buffer, pagesize=A4, rightMargin=30, leftMargin=30, topMargin=30,
                            bottomMargin=18)
    doc.pagesize = landscape(A4)
    elements = []
    fontdiractory="/home/osman/font/"
    pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('bangla', os.path.join(fontdiractory, 'Siyamrupali_1_01.ttf')))
    styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
    style_centre = ParagraphStyle(name='centre', parent=styles['Heading2'],fontName='bangla', alignment=TA_CENTER)

    p = Paragraph("গণপ্রজাতন্ত্রী বাংলাদেশ", style_centre)
    elements.append(p)
    p = Paragraph("UEO Office", style_centre)
    elements.append(p)
    p = Paragraph("Upazilla: "+'Tongipara'+ " District: "+'Gopalgonj', style_centre)
    elements.append(p)

    data = [
        ['Govt. Primary School','','','','','','',''],
        ['Ebtedaiye Madrasha','','','','','','',''],
        ['গণপ্রজাতন্ত্রী বাংলাদেশ','','','','','','',''],
        ['Primary school','','','','','','',''],
        ['Primary school','','','','','','',''],
        ['Primary school','','','','','','','']
    ]

    # TODO: Get this line right instead of just copying it from the docs
    style = TableStyle([('ALIGN', (1, 1), (-2, -2), 'RIGHT'),
                        ('TEXTCOLOR', (1, 1), (-2, -2), colors.red),
                        ('VALIGN', (0, 0), (0, -1), 'TOP'),
                        ('TEXTCOLOR', (0, 0), (0, -1), colors.blue),
                        ('ALIGN', (0, -1), (-1, -1), 'CENTER'),
                        ('VALIGN', (0, -1), (-1, -1), 'MIDDLE'),
                        ('TEXTCOLOR', (0, -1), (-1, -1), colors.green),
                        ('INNERGRID', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.25, colors.black),
                        ('BOX', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.25, colors.black),
                        ])

    data2 = [[Paragraph(cell, style_centre) for cell in row] for row in data]
    t = Table(data2)
    t.setStyle(style)
    elements.append(t)

    doc.build(elements)
    response.write(buffer.getvalue())
    buffer.close()
    return response
```

[image: Output Image]

Comment: if you have solution for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68283850/generating-pdf-in-bangla-language-with-reportlab-python-library-broken-joint-let) plz help.

Comment: @Jibon , I skip ReportLab from my codebase and use another library  [weasyprint](https://weasyprint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html). it`s handy and useful I think.

Answer (score 1):

I can see Default canvas_basefontname is "Helvetica" [see in reportlab config doc](https://github.com/eduardocereto/reportlab/blob/master/src/reportlab/rl_config.py) so I change the canvas_basefontname to my required font. that`s it. I add bellow code fount in this [link](https://pairlist2.pair.net/pipermail/reportlab-users/2015-June/011391.html).

```
from reportlab import rl_config
rl_config._SAVED['canvas_basefontname'] = 'bangla'
rl_config._startUp()
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer after hours of hours research by [this](https://github.com/MS-Jahan/unicode2bijoy) GitHub repo.

Change the text Unicode to Bijoy by this repo.
Draw the Bijoy text on canvas. Thats it.

I hope it helps someone.